# Why SetWindowLongPtr always returns zero when processing WM_CREATE message?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, win32gui

I'm quite new to win32 programming, and I'm using the `SetWindowLongPtr` in the code block of `WM_CREATE` message processing, but it always returns zero. The program is rather simple, is there anything I was missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef _WIN64
#define SET_WINDOW_LONG_PTR SetWindowLongPtr
#else
#define SET_WINDOW_LONG_PTR SetWindowLong
#endif

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

  WNDCLASS wc = {0};
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.lpszClassName = L"MyWindowClass";
  wc.cbClsExtra = sizeof(LONG_PTR);

  if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
    // Handle error...
  }

  HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"MyWindowClass", L"My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

  if (!hWnd) {
    // Handle error...
  }

  ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

  MSG msg = {0};
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
      LONG_PTR MYDATA = (LONG_PTR)malloc(sizeof(int));
      int result = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, MYDATA);
      // int result = SetWindowLongPtr (hWnd, DWLP_USER, MYDATA);   //this won't work either 
      // result is zero
      break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Build command:

```
gcc main.c -o test.exe -mwindows -lcomctl32
```

Things I've tried so far:

1. use `DWLP_USER` instead of `GWLP_USERDATA`;
2. use the platform-specific `SET_WINDOW_LONG_PTR` macro instead of `SetWindowLongPtr`;

It still returns zero.

**Update:**
Following the advice of @wohlstad, I use `SetLastError(0)` and then `GetLastError` to get the error, `GetLastError` returns zero, seems that there's nothing wrong with the use of `SetWindowLongPtr`, though some part of the official documentation seems a bit confusing:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`SetWindowLongPtr` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra):

> Return value
>
> Type: LONG_PTR
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the **previous value of
> the specified offset**.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
> information, call GetLastError.
>
> If the previous value is zero and the function succeeds, the return
> value is zero, but the function does not clear the last error
> information. To determine success or failure, **clear the last error
> information by calling SetLastError with 0, then call
> SetWindowLongPtr**. Function failure will be indicated by a return value
> of zero and a GetLastError result that is nonzero.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Therefore, a return value of `0` does not necessarily indicate an error. In order to perform proper error checking, you need to call [`SetLastError(0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-setlasterror) before calling `SetWindowLongPtr()`, and then check whether [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) still returns `0` (no-error) afterwards.

```
SetLastError(0);
LONG_PTR result = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, MYDATA);
if ((result == 0) && (GetLastError() != 0)) {
    // error setting data
}
```

Comment: *"and check whether `GetLastError` still return `0` (no-error) after it."* - That's not sufficient. You'll also have to verify that `SetWindowLongPtr` did return `0`.

Comment: @IInspectable that was my intention. Anyway my answer was edited to make it clear.